# how to show tool tip while material ui slider?

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, material-ui

[image]how to highlight the x-axis point when i slide using `material ui` slider in chart js, or show the tooltip for the x-axis point when i slide.

Comment: Question unclear

Comment: Your question is really unclear, but this can helps you: https://github.com/tariqwest/material-ui-slider-label